# How to extract password protected zipx file (contains xlsx) using Java?

Tags: java, aes

I am unable to unzip a password protected zipx file (contains xlsx) using Java. Encryption method AES-256 LZMA.

I have tried Apache Common Compress and Lingla.zip4j. But unable to extract. 
It seems that Compression Types LZMA does not support by Lingla.zip4j.

[Image: For CRC and Encryption method detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvUYj.png)

Is there any other way I can extract?

**Apache Common Code**

```
File file = new File("H:\\WorkDoc\\afile.zipx");    
            byte[] inputData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            fis.read(inputData); //read file into bytes[]
            fis.close();

            String password = "password";
            byte[] pass = password.getBytes();

            SeekableInMemoryByteChannel inMemoryByteChannel = new SeekableInMemoryByteChannel(inputData);
            SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(inMemoryByteChannel, pass);
            SevenZArchiveEntry entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry();
            sevenZFile.read(); // read current entry's data
```

**Error**

```
java.io.IOException: Bad 7z signature
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.readHeaders(SevenZFile.java:250)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:165)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile.<init>(SevenZFile.java:136)
    at com.concept.utilities.zip.ApacheComm.main(ApacheComm.java:33)
```

Comment: Do you have the password? Do you know in what order it was zipped and encrypted (like is the zip encrypted, or are the files in the zip encrypted)? Do you have any code that you have written so far to show us what you have done? Maybe the code is wrong...

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog](https://contrapunctus.net/league/haques/lzmajio/), the package net.contrapunctus.lzma provides implementations of LzmaInputStream and LzmaOutputStream that interact with underlying LZMA encoders and decoders running in separate threads. So, it may become useful for you.

Comment: How do you know he needs Lzma?

Comment: @rabbitguy OP said: *"It seems that Compression Types LZMA does not support by Lingla.zip4j."*

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/league/lzmajio/blob/master/net/contrapunctus/lzma/LzmaInputStream.java) is the package implementation but i am not sure if it also support passwords or not.